# Uninstalling xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I want to completely reinstall xampp. After executing uninstall.exe, I was left with folder like php, apache, mysql, which couldn't be deleted. Apache service seems to be disabled. How can I solve that?

Comment: Have you restarted the machine?

Comment: I have to take a break...it helped, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the machine and try deleting the folders again.